# Is it possible to read a sensor via ethernetip without a PLC?

Tags: python, sensors, communication, ethernet, plc

I have a keyence sensor `FD-XA2` which is mounted on the communication unit `NU-EP1`. I connected it to my PC with an Ethernet cable. I thought it would be rather easy to read the values with python by just receiving them from the Ethernet-connection. But I have no idea how to set up the communication between the sensor and PC. I was able to create a client and server with the `socket` package on my PC, which is working fine. But I have literally no idea if the sensor needs to be a client or server. How do I set up the whole thing correctly?

The manufacturer support told me they just have experience with reading the sensor when it is connected to a PLC. This would be my second option. But I thought maybe I can just read the sensor without a PLC.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this question is of value? [Read/write values using Ethernet/IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461069/read-write-values-using-ethernet-ip)

Comment: EIP is heavy protocol.  Writing a new implementation from the ground up would be exceptionally difficult for a single developer and an enormous waste of time generally.  Use a library or a PLC.  Library recommendations are off-topic.